# Create/initialize objects in shared memory (opened by mmap())

Tags: c, memory, gnu, shared

I created my shared memory and mapped my object with following code:

```
shmfd = shm_open(SHMOBJ_PATH, O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
ftruncate(shmfd, shared_seg_size);
bbuffer = (boundedBuffer *)mmap(NULL, shared_seg_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmfd, 0);
```

Now I need to initialize and add/remove items to/from bbuffer. When I try to add/remove, I get Segmentation Fault: 11, which indicates the program accessed a memory location that was not assigned. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: show us the code and where the violation occurs.

Comment: Violation occurs when I try to access bbuffer for any reason.

Comment: did you test bbufer is not NULL ? and shm_open() return value ?

Comment: bbuffer is not NULL. Its adress is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess:

- perhaps you don't have the header file for `mmap` included
- **and** you are on an architecture with 64 bit `void*` and 32 bit `int`

What could happen there is that the compiler takes `mmap` as returning `int` by default, casts this into a pointer and by that clashes the higher order bits.

Never cast return values from functions such as `malloc` or `mmap`, and always take the warnings of your compiler seriously.

Comment: I included <sys/mman.h>. I removed cast, I get no warning from compiler.